# How to convert decimal to string without part after floating point, if it's zero, and in specific currency format?

Tags: c#, formatting, tostring

For example I have several decimals:

```
decimal[] arr = { 1, (decimal)1.1, (decimal)1.00 };
```

they represent price in russian rubles:

```
var overrideCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU");
```

when I use:

```
foreach (var d in arr)
{
     string s = d.ToString("c", overrideCulture);
     Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

I get

```
1,00p.
1,10p.
1,00p.
```

as result, but what I need is, if fraction is zero, I don't want it to be displayed but I need to keep currency format. in this example I want to get:

```
1p.
1,10p.
1p.
```

I can simply get of fractions like:

```
foreach (var d in arr)
{
     string s = d.ToString("#.##", overrideCulture);
     Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

but currency format will be lost.

```
string s = d.ToString("#.##c", overrideCulture);
```

also does'n work, I get `1c` or `1,1c`

Is there some NOT tricky way to get such formatting like I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a single format string that will do that but one way would be:

```
string format = (d == Math.Round(d,0)) ? "c0" : "c";
string s = d.ToString(format, overrideCulture);
```

if d may have more than 2 decimal places and you want to not show decimals for any value that would round to `.00` try

```
string format = (Math.Round(d,2) == Math.Round(d,0)) ? "c0" : "c";
string s = d.ToString(format, overrideCulture);
```

As a side note you can avoid a cast be defining the constants as decimal literals:

```
decimal[] arr = { 1m, 1.1m, 1.00m };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string res = @decimal.ToString(@decimal == decimal.Truncate(@decimal) ? "c0" : "c", culture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can simply append the currency symbol:

```
string symbol = overrideCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
foreach (var d in arr)
{
    string s = d.ToString("#.##", overrideCulture) + symbol;
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```